# "it's being a holiday" is it correct in this context

Tags: sentence-construction

Today I have heard a sentence:

> Today it's being a holiday what are you doing up there?

Does it mean:

Although it's a holiday, you're so busy.

Is it correct to say in this context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently understood the meaning correctly, but there should be no *it's* in that sentence; and a comma would make it clearer:

> Today being a holiday, what are you doing up there?

To grammarians the first phrase is an [**absolute** construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction); see explanation and more examples there.